# NFS prevents machine from shutting down

Tags: 14.04, networking, shutdown, nfs

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and use ifplugd as network manager. I also have 2 NFS shares set up.

If I unmount those shares beforehand, OS shuts down just fine, but if I don't, it never shuts down (I left it running for 3 hours and it didn't shut down).

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Probably write or modify `/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action` to unmount when the interface goes down?

Comment: What command should be used to unmount NFS shares?

Comment: You say in your question: "If I unmount those shares beforehand..." How do you do it then?

Comment: I do it manually, like "umount /media/bla", so it's pretty dirty solution. But, I've just realized that I can use "umount -a -t nfs"

Comment: I appended "umount -a -t nfs" and it only made it worse - ifplugd can't be killed (timeout).

Comment: why would you append it? Wouldn't you want it unmounted *before* the network goes down?

Comment: Yes, I want those shares to unmount before network goes down, so I appended that line to /etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I can use **autofs** instead of fstab to mount my NFS shares.

In order to make it work, follow the steps :

1. Open /etc/auto.master in your editor of choice and add `/$catalog $configpath` at the end of this file, where **$catalog** is the folder where you want your shares to be mounted (note that you have to create that directory manually), and **$configpath** is the path for shares config file.
2. Edit your config file at $configpath in the following manner :
   `$sharename $server:/$sharepath`

With following config your share will be mounted at **$catalog/$sharename**.

There's also another workaround to this problem, which is adding `soft` option to your shares in fstab.